How to get data from responseJSON object?
I have the below javascript;
var XX = $.getJSON("skiareas-polygons.geojson",function(data){
    // add data to map
    L.geoJson(data, {
        style: function (feature) {
            return { 
                color : 'black',
                weight: 1,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: 'grey',
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            };
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});

I am having difficulty understanding how to access the response object.  In particular, I can see the responseJSON below with indexes 0, 1 and 2.  What is I wanted to
(1) access responseJSON.features.0.properties.name?
(2) wanted the geojson version of all the data in all indexes or just 0?
Sorry but I hope I am clear.  Maybe I just need some pointers in the right direction or links to read please?


Or responseJSON of a getJSON object is undefined? or How retrieve responseJSON property of a jquery $.ajax object

Use simple responseJSON.features[0].properties.name
Since features is an array and contains 3 elements, square brackets are used to access an element, not the dot notation (dot notation is used to access an object's property).
